# AngularJS ng-class and form validation behaviour

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, ng-class

Have a very strang issue, which I think should work but doesn't behave as it should:

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': !emailstatus && userBooking.email.$dirty, 'has-success': emailstatus}">
    <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 col-xs-12">

        <input class="form-control input-lg" name="email" type="text"placeholder="Mail" ng-model="formData.email" ng-change="email()">
        <label style="margin-top:-8px;"> Ange mailadress</label></br>{{emailmessage}}
    </div>
</div>
```

Simple form validation, I have a function email() which checks if the email written in the email field is already in the database, it should then set the form to error, but this should only happen if someone touched the form.

However it does not behave that way, the success is fine, it turns green as the email is not in the database

[image]

and it is grey in the beginning when no one has written anything in it.

[image: From the beginning]

However whenever the email IS in the database, the form just turns grey and not red? But when checking the variable emailstatus it is most certainly "false" thus should be true in the expression.
[image: It IS already in the database but the form is grey instead of red?]

And finally to make it more strange, if I change the ng-class expression to:

```
   {'has-error': !emailstatus, 'has-success': emailstatus}
```

it works as expected, except for the unacceptable reason that it is red even if the user has not touched it ($pristine).

[image: Working but is red even if it is $pristine]

Angular function email():

```
 var checkEmail = function() {
    params = {
        email: $scope.formData.email
    };

    $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'php/emailcheck.php',
            data: $.param(params), // pass in data as strings
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
            } // set the headers so angular passing info as form data (not request payload)
        })
        .success(function(data) {
            if (!data) {
                // if not successful, bind errors to error variables
                console.log("error");
            } else {
                if (data === "Yes") {
                    $scope.emailmessage = "Adressen finns redan registrerad, vänligen välj en annan."
                    $scope.emailstatus = false

                } else if (data === "No") {
                    $scope.emailmessage = "Adressen är ledig!"
                    $scope.emailstatus = true
                } else {
                    console.log("nothing happens if the code is wrong")
                }
            }
        });
};
```

Comment: show respective angular code.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this problem:

*it works as expected, except for the unacceptable reason that it is red even if the user has not touched it ($pristine)*

use $touched on the property as well (>=Angular 1.3 only).

This will ensure that the validation kicks in only if the input is:

- invalid
- the user has clicked into the input (i.e. touched it)